# Altered Incorrectly File Permissions

Tags: 14.04, permissions, lubuntu

I was wanting to grant a new user read/write access to the directory `/usr/share/applications` and to do such I ran

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /usr/share/applications
```

Now my entire file structure is completely wonkers!

What do I need to do to restore?  AM I better off just re-installing?

Comment: I believe that directory `/usr/share/applications` is usually owned by `root` and I am not sure why you would want to change permissions in here for another user? At least in my case most files in there have these (read-only) permissions: `-rw-r--r--` If you are in fact looking for a shared directory to host applications - this is probably not the best place for it.

Comment: @Chris - I was wanting to give myself write access so that I could create a new .desktop file in order for a shortcut to be created.

Comment: you are better off installing with `sudo` than changing write access to that directory. You can already write any file you want in there using `sudo`

Comment: Even though it does fix your problem, I would not recommend going with the accepted answer. As I explained in the comment below - you would allow write and execution permissions in that directory - a better place to put custom applications, etc is usually under: `/usr/local`, so `/usr/local/share/applications` in this case, maybe this helps as well: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run:

```
sudo chmod -R 644 /usr/share/applications
sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/applications
```

And your back where you started.

Chris added:

> chmod changes the permissions of each given file
>   according to mode, where mode describes the permissions to modify.
>   Mode can be specified with octal numbers or with letters.
>
> A better
>   place to put custom applications, etc is usually under: /usr/local, so
>   /usr/local/share/applications in this case, maybe this helps as well:
>   [tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html)

Linux filesystem hierarchy, easy reading: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview

Read more on "chmod" here: http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!!!!!  --- what did the command you posted above do?

Comment: Each of those "magic" numbers refers to execution rights in this order: **owner,group,other** (7 means write,read,exec permissions, 5 means execute and read permissions). 755 means read,write,exec permissions for the owner, and read,execute permissions for the group and others. Practically, everyone with access to that machine can now read and execute files in that directory, but only the owner can write in there. Read more here: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/checking-linux-file-permissions-with-ls/

Comment: @IzznogooooD please correct me if I'm wrong, but that should probably be: `sudo chmod -R 644 /usr/share/applications` ?  Only the owner (root) should write in that directory and nobody should have execution permissions there.

Comment: @Chris you're right!  I will update the answer.

Comment: @MoreBrawnLessBrains you can run these commands again (It wont screw anything up). :)

Comment: @Chris - if I use 644 nothing displays when I click on the lubuntu orb - if I use 755 everything shows as it should when I click the orb.

Comment: The only difference between 755 and 644 is the right to execute, but make sure all directories have this right (as @IzznogooooD suggested). Make sure you did `sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/applications` after `sudo chmod -R 644 /usr/share/applications`

Comment: and possibly `sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/applications/kde4` and any other directory in there